# Make TabItem select first nested button when clicked (WPF MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, radio-button, tabitem

As the title says, I would like the first nested Button to be selected (this button selects a view) when the tab item is clicked. Here is my code below:

```
      <TabItem Header="Scheduling">
            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabStackPanelStyle}">
                <RadioButton Command="{Binding BookResourceCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabButtonStyle}">Book</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Command="{Binding NewResourceCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabButtonStyle}">New</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Command="{Binding EditResourceCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabButtonStyle}">Edit</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Command="{Binding DeleteResourceCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabButtonStyle}">Delete</RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
```

This TabItem sits in a TabControl with a few more similar TabItems. All I want to do is have the TabItem select the first RadioButton (by default) when it is clicked. These radio buttons change a user control in my ViewModel.

I know it would be possible using EventTriggers associated with the TabItem but there must be a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this situation you can use `Binding`:

`TabItem`

```
<TabItem x:Name="MyTabItem" Header="Two">
    <Label Content="Some Content" />
</TabItem>
```

`RadioButton`

```
<RadioButton Name="MyButton" Content="Two" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MyTabItem, Path=IsSelected}" />
```

If you want to be when you click on the `RadioButton`, the tab is not selected, use `Mode=OneWay`:

```
<RadioButton Name="MyButton" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MyTabItem, Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: If the user chooses a different radio button and then cycles between this tab and another, it will cause the user's selection to be reset. Not sure if that behavior is what is intended or not.

Comment: Well, as I understand, if he has 4 tabs for example, the button is selected on the selected tab. For example: Tab Books, the button of the current tab - books.

Comment: The above does select the button however the command associated to that button does not fire. I need the command to fire because that command shows a UserControl.

Comment: @francisg3: Why did you not write in your question about `Command`? If you have a command is triggered by the event `Checked` (for example), you will likely have to be done through the event triggers.